# DataBinding in custom class

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I wanna make a databinding in a custom class.
But it seems different from normal databinding.

For example, I have a custom class DisplayInfo with a properties DisplayText(string), DisplayStyle(string) and DisplayDescription(string).

and in another custom class ViewUI that contains a property DisplayData which is of type DisplayInfo.

for example:

```
public class ViewUI 
{
    ....
    public DisplayInfo DisplayData { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

I want to do DataBinding of the DisplayText in the Xaml. How could I do so?

reference:

```
<Page ......>

.....
.....
.....

    <ViewUI .......>

        <ViewUI.DisplayData>
            <DisplayInfo Description="Description 123456...." DisplayStyle="Style123" DisplayText = "{Binding.....}"/> <!-- (How to do databinding here or in other place?) -->
        </ViewUI.DisplayData>


    </ViewUI>

</Page>
```

Comment: Can you post more code? Binding to ViewUI should be rather simple (and probably doesn't require dependency properties to make it work), but your XAML puzzles me - what are you trying to do? Are you declaring ViewUI as a resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change properties in custom class to dependency properties. If property of your class is dependency property then you are able to bind it in xaml.

For more info about dependency property visit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358.aspx

> What Is a Dependency Property?
>
> ---
>
> You can enable what would otherwise be a common language runtime
>   (CLR) property to support styling, data binding, inheritance,
>   animations, and default values by implementing it as a dependency
>   property. Dependency properties are properties that are registered
>   with the WPF property system by calling the Register method (or
>   RegisterReadOnly), and that are backed by a DependencyProperty
>   identifier field. Dependency properties can be used only by
>   DependencyObject types, but DependencyObject is quite high in the WPF
>   class hierarchy, so the majority of classes available in WPF can
>   support dependency properties. For more information about dependency
>   properties and some of the terminology and conventions used for
>   describing them in this SDK, see Dependency Properties Overview.

Comment: Depending on the binding the OP probably doesn't require dependency properties.

Comment: may be but if you want to bind property in xaml it is required.